# Perform Default Action for each Function in a Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created some directives which have some functions, something like this:

```
myCtrl.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            'something': '='
        },
        link: function (scope, el, attr) { 
             function func1(){
                 //some stuff
                 scope.$apply();
             }
             function func2(){
                 //some stuff
                 scope.$apply();
             }
             function func3(){
                 //some stuff
                 scope.$apply();
             }
             //...
        }
    }
});
```

I have to call `scope.$apply()` in all the functions to update the view. In addition I don't want to define them in the controller. I don't know if there is a trick to avoid this kind of pattern. It is working but I think it's not a good solution.

**UPDATE**

There are more than 10 directives which we've created for some shapes, e.g. rectangle, circle, square etc. In these functions, which I called `$apply` in them, some methods like drag and scale are implemented. So I need to call `$apply` to modify changes in model and consequently the view will be updated. I don't know how can I make them able to aware `scope` automatically unless I write about 100 functions in a controller!
In addition, I'm using some 3rd party libraries like `d3.js`. Some event like `clicked` are bounded for calling these functions.

Comment: Your functions are attached to the `scope`, right? I.e. `scope.func1 = function() {};`?

Comment: @sp00m No, they are not.

Comment: Have you tried declaring a controller within the directive?

Comment: @Gnarlywhale I'm not allowed to do that because there are a dozen of directives which I need to declare the controller in them!

Comment: describe how these functions getting called

Comment: What do you do with these functions? In your snippet it looks like they have private visibility (are not accessible from anywhere else). Can you post more of your code please?

Comment: What exactly is your question? And what are these functions supposed to be used for? Without the context it's impossible to say whether it's correct to use $apply or not.

Comment: @TahsisClaus Check the update section please.

Comment: In theory, you could have the directive trigger for a general action (such as a drag event), pick one of your functions to call, then calls $apply after your function has finished. It's hard to say without seeing the full code of the directive.

Comment: @TahsisClaus could you make a sample for what you said please?

Comment: You could have something like function pointers (sorry I come from C). You have your func1 func2 etc.. and `function execFunc(action) {  action(); scope.$apply() }` to which you pass the correct function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real truth is that you need to call `$scope.$apply()` whenever you're changing something outside angular digest cycle. Angular detects the changes by [dirty checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/databinding-in-angularjs) during the digest cycle.

`$timeout is also doing $apply ($rootScope.$apply())`

Check [Angular source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.5/src/ng/timeout.js#L64).

What I can suggest is create helper function which will handle that. Example:

```
var ngAware = function (fnCallback) {
    return function () {
        var result = fnCallback.apply(this, arguments);    
        $scope.$apply();
        return result;
    };   
};   

// usage
function func1 () {
    // impl...
}
var ngFunc1 = ngAware(func1);
// or
var func2 = ngAware(function func2 () {
    // impl...
});
```

Comment: I think your solution is really near to what I need, the only difference is the functions that I've mentioned are some events, e.g. click or drag events.

Comment: You can use them as regular functions.
Example: $('stg').click(func2); or
$('stg').click(ngAware(function(event) {
  // impl..
}));

Comment: Could you make a sample on fiddle or somewhere else please?

Comment: Yes, here is one simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/69mub4nz/
Here instead of $scope.$apply() we are showing additional alert.

Answer (score 0):

## Sure you need `apply()`?

`apply()` is used when integrating 3rd party libraries (such as jQuery). In most cases, if you are not hooking up 3rd party javascript libraries, you can avoid `$apply()` by using the build in binding mechanism

**For instance,** the following snippet will call `func1` using a 3 seconds timeout callback. then, `func1`  will manipulate the scope variable `something` and the view will be updated without the need to trigger `$apply()`

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.value = 'Hello';
});


app.directive('myDirective', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template:'<h1>{{something}}</h1>',
        scope: {
            'something': '='
        },
        link: function (scope, el, attr) { 
             function func1(){
                scope.something += ' ' + scope.something;
             }
             
             $timeout(func1, 3000);
        }
    }
});
```

html

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <my-directive something="value"></my-directive>
</body>
```

## http://plnkr.co/edit/42VYs0W2BC5mjpaVWQg3?p=preview

- perhaps if you explain more about your use case i could expand my answer to your specific needs

Comment: Using $apply in directives isn't that hacky as its needed for interfacing anything outside of angular (so DOM and browser events too). Many of the ng directives use $apply.

Answer (score 0):

**wraps the function within $scope.$apply()**

check this :

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.value = 'Hello';
});


app.directive('myDirective', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template:'<h1>{{something}}</h1>',
        scope: {
            'something': '='
        },
        link: function (scope, el, attr) { 
            scope.$apply(function(){

                function func1(){
                    //some stuff
                }

                function func2(){
                    //some stuff
                }

                function func3(){
                    //some stuff
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have common functionality in you directives (circle, square, etc) you should group it. By example, we could have a directive to **drag**

```
.directive('ngDraggable', [function () {

    return {
        link: function ($scope) {

            var stopHandler = function () {

                $scope.apply(function () {
                    // Code to handler the end of the dag event

                    // Notify the other directive.
                    $scope.$emit('dragStopped', data);
                });
            };

            // Initialization of the drag functionality.
        }
    }
}])
```

You can used as

```
<div ng-circle ng-draggable></div>
```

So, you earn three thing. First, the *circle* directive can do changes in its *scope* without call to `$apply`, because `$emit` already is in the digest cycle. Second, you only use `$apply` where is necessary. And third, you improve the performance by use `$apply` in scopes most small and with less children.

You could merge this answer with the answer of @sasko_dh

Maybe the [Observer Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer) could be you useful.